# get last completed (some condition) id while counting

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the last completed task id of the child table while counting all the child records and completed child records:

```
set @tmp := 0;
select
  count(*) total,
  count(if(completed=1, 1, null)) completed,
  @tmp:=if(completed=1, task_id, @tmp) last_completed_task_id
from child_table where parent_id = 6
order by sequence
```

Here is some sample data:

```
id    parent_id completed task_id sequence 
  526         6         1       1        1
 1653         6         0       5        2
 2749         6         0      20        3
 3840         6         0      21        4
 4913         6         1      22        5
 5983         6         0      23        6
 7063         6         0      25        7
 7183         6         0      26        8
 8241         6         1      27        9
 9317         6         0      28       10
10380         6         0      29       11
```

So final result should be like that:

- total: 11
- completed: 3
- last_completed_task_id: 27

I know how to get it with separate queries, but I wish to get it with one query if possible.

Comment: ive edited the question, ive messed up with different parent_id but main thing was 27, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cros join between the count and the max task_id eg:

```
select 
  count(*) total,
  count(if(completed=1, 1, null)) completed,
  t.last_completed_task_id
  from child_table
  cross join (
  select max(task_id) last_completed_task_id
  from child_table
  where parent_id = 6
  and completed=1 ) t
  where parent_id = 6
```

Comment: sounds cool, but could do explain why that works? also you did not use sequence field

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili  this work simply selecting the last completed task using the completed task and the max id .. this result in place on the same rows of the two count using a cross join alias  a cartesian product between the two query (two query both with a single rows) .. hope this is useful  .  and last the use fo sequence seems not necessary for obatin the result  .. each result is indenpend respect the order ..

Comment: I assumed that the last  is the one with max(task_id)  if the value have others meaning  .. let me know  ..  ..could  be is max(id) ..teh concept remain the same

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the last completed id using conditional aggregation:

```
select count(*),
       sum(is_completed = 1),
       max(case when is_completed = 1 then id end) as last_completed_id
from child_table ct
where parent_id = 6;
```

If `task_id` is increasing -- as in your sample data -- you can just use `task_id` rather than `id` in the `max()`.

Otherwise, just join the table back in:

```
select cnt, cnt_completed, ct2.task_id
from (select count(*) as cnt,
             sum(is_completed = 1) as cnt_completed,
             max(case when is_completed = 1 then id end) as last_completed_id
      from child_table ct
      where parent_id = 6
     ) x join
     child_table ct2
     on x.last_completed_id = ct2.id
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, its just in this sample that task id is increasing with sequence, but that might not be the case. My actual point was if `@tmp:=if(completed=1, task_id, @tmp) last_completed_task_id` thi statement is executed for every 11 records then there should be way to get the right id, based on the conditions, but that looks impossible.

Comment: I prefered not to do joins coz the parent data is very big and i am looking for optimal solution, that performs fast on large scales

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili Why do you think joins are sub-optimal?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili . . . The `join` is fine if `child_table` has an index on `id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
select count(*) total,
  count(if(completed=1, 1, null)) completed,
  (select task_id from child_table where parent_id = 6 and completed = 1 order by sequence desc limit 1) as last_completed_task_id
from child_table 
where parent_id = 6
```

Comment: thanks, but as i mentioned i know how to do it with two queries